# Capture child process id and save it to a file to kill that

Tags: shell, scripting

I am creating a auto script where I want to kill the process of this jar file every one hour.

I want to capture this process and will use kill -9 process from a file.
I almost achived it but realized 16457 and 9845 ( characters must not same every time , sometime 5 characters 
process id and sometime might be different . )
So the sed command I was using is not working properly.

If please review and advise me how to capture this process id regardless characters.

```
[tresouser@localhost ~]$ ps -ef|grep treso.jar
tresouser    16457      1  0 13:40 ?        00:00:00 /u02/jarloc/treso/treso.jar 
tresouser    88861  88807  0 13:41 pts/2    00:00:00 grep treso.jar
```

```
[tresouser@localhost ~]$ ps -ef|grep treso.jar
tresouser     9845      1  0 12:40 ?        00:00:00 /u02/jarloc/treso/treso.jar 
tresouser    88861  88807  0 12:45 pts/2    00:00:00 grep treso.jar
```

Comment: If the process you are attempting to capture the pid of is indeed a child of your script, then your task is simple: the pid is stored in `$!` after you spawn it.  If that process is not a child of your script, you should edit the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
ps -C -o pid,comm |grep treso.jar |awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{print $2}'
```

Let's break it down with some explanation...

```
ps -C -o pid,comm
```

This will list all processes and the associated command (you can swap out `comm` for `command` if you want to filter based on the command and the arguments)

```
|grep treso.jar
```

This will filter out any commands that don't include `treso.jar`

```
|awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{print $2}'
```

This will split the columns based on spaces, we then take the second column and print it (there is a space before the PID so the first column is blank)

Comment: Don't pipe grep to awk.  `grep treso.jar |awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{print $2}'` is better written `awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '/treso.jar/{print $2}'`

Comment: That works as well, I personally don't see a big issue with piping grep into awk though, it's unlikely you will see output buffering from ps